# Повторяющиеся код CSS

Tags: css, css3, scss

Как оптимизировать повторение кода CSS

Я знаю про переменные в CSS и как их использовать, но как сделать так, чтобы можно было занести в переменную несколько значений?

Например

```
* {  
   --cad: {
       color: red;
       border: 2px solid blue;
       width: 100px;
       height: 100px;
   }
}
```

Как мне использовать этот блок, чтобы не переписывать и не повторять тонну CSS кода? Или это невозможно?
Или есть другие способы, которые позволяют вставить в блок несколько значений?

Comment: Судя по описанию проблемы, вам нужно просто использовать классы

Comment: В препроцессоре less есть миксины `.mixin(){
  color:white;
  background:blue;
  margin:5px;
}

#parent>*{
  .mixin;
}`
В других препроцессорах вроде бы тоже есть миксины